# Flutter - How to have audio play when phone screen is off

Tags: dart, flutter, audio-streaming, flutter-dependencies

I am building an app where there is a person is speaking, kinda like a podcast, and I would like the listener to be able to listen when the screen is off.

I am using Flutter, and the media player is complete, but if i turn the phone screen off, the media stops.

I have no idea how to treat this so when you turn off the screen, the media will still play.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a background services plugin. I recommend the audio_services plugin available here: https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service#-installing-tab-[image: A screenshot of the plugin description. Goodluck]